# Plumbing Faucet: Water Pressure vs Water Flow Difference

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, water-pressure

They always say water flow (Gallons per Minute) and water pressure (Weight force) are two different things. Say I have a faucet with 1.8 GPM Aerator.

1) If I increase water pressure in my home, wouldn't water have to come out of the faucet faster? Or how does it compensate, does less water come out?

2) Honestly, I feel like when I upgraded my aerator from 1.2 GPM to 1.8 GPM, the water flow was more, but was Pressure was less. Does that typically happen to people?

Related Question: [Sink Angle Valve: Fully Open or closed Tiny Bit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170211/sink-angle-valve-fully-open-or-closed-tiny-bit?newreg=31fa4e6f8fa548a5af1b4d6a6c7a547e)

Comment: The faucet could theoretically be designed with non-linear flow characteristics so that the flow rate (gal/min) would not change very much over a range of internal pressure in the supply lines, but I don't know if actual faucets are designed this way.  The pressure of the water stream *coming out of the faucet* can be greater if the stream is confined by a nozzle. This would actually reduce the flow rate but give more force as it strikes a surface on which it is directed.

Comment: ok thanks feel free to answer two questions above

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, once the water leaves the faucet, the pressure is zero, but the water has speed. When the water hits your hand, you feel force. The aerator on the faucet can be designed so the speed of the water is lower, even though the gallons per minute is greater. Try holding a pint measuring cup under the faucet and use a stopwatch to see how long it takes to fill it, then calculate the gallons per minute.

Answer (score 0):

The flow limiters in most faucets is based on 60psi. I have adjusted these in the cases they cannot be removed with a simple drill bit several sizes larger than the existing hole, in my last home the entire place had 3/4” copper even after the shower valves that were 1/2”. Seeing the massive supply’s and plumbing I set my master suite with a 6’ jacuzzi tub and a huge rain forest 2 head shower , it sucked , until I found the flow restrictors in each of the heads , by the design I could not remove them but opening the plastic gave me what I wanted in fact it was so good I added a ball valve on one of the heads because if alone that’s all me or the wife needed but we are both big people so we would turn on both heads and we loved that shower. 
Added:
To provide a easier to understand answer when you have a fixed pressure and you increase the flow by increasing the orifice size the pressure is reduced so the spray may not shoot as far but there will be more water flowing. I have not seen a restrictor that is adjustable.

Comment: uh ok, thank you, can you answer the questions above directly so I can send points? this is more of story, thanks

Comment: can you post a new answer?? this does not suffice thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for other than pressure and flow . An airator increases the apparent volume by adding air to the stream other than that its pressure and flow.